# MVC 3 Architecture?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I don't know whether this is right forum to ask about MVC3 Framework.

Actually my Project Manager asked me to do next project in MVC3 achitecture. I never worked even in MVC.

Can anyone help me to provide a tutorials link about MVC3?
Is it right to go with MVC3 without knowing about MVC?

Please help?

Answer (score 5):

Well since you mention MVC 3 your manager probably means Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3, and the perfect starting place to learn about ASP.NET MVC is [www.asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

You will find a lot of helpful tutorials and video presentation that will help get you started.

Comment: Thanks Nikos, here i am going with this link

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite easy ( = comfortable) to learn basics of ASP.NET MVC nowadays.
There are many great resources at [**www.asp.net/mvc**](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

I can also recommend videos from MIX events by Scott Hanselman. You can look for them in [MIX archive](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/mix) (years 09-11) or at his site [www.hanselman.com](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CategoryView.aspx?category=ASP.NET%20MVC). He + guys like [Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/) and [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/) did project called Nerddinner which **was** good starting point for beginners (during days of MVC1 and MVC2), because there are videos about it and also free ebook (you can get all at nerddinner.com - link is in footer), but its a bit aged now and there are already newer tutorials aiming newer versions of ASP.NET MVC3 directly at official ASP.NET MVC site.

So your best starting point for ASP.NET MVC3 really is the [www.asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc) site and `1. Getting Started` section ;) Read overview, start following the first tutorials (first ASP.NET MVC Applicaton and ASP.NET MVC Music Store). Then when you will get into troubles with something specific, you can come back here and ask again.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Btw: if you will have some free time to watch some of those MIX videos, I can't stretch enough how great are those done by Scott Hanselman (just do searh for his name in video archives). His presentations are usually very entertaining and educational at same time :) Good luck with ASP.NET MVC anyway.

Answer (score 2):

[Steven Sanderson's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228865) is actually the good one to start. Not only it explains MVC framework in depth, but provides comparison with other web frameworks and all the pros/cons it has got. After reading first chapters, you'll undestand why your project manager asked so :). The book is is mvc2 - so there're some points explained that are already old (WebForms view engine) but anyways, book gives good knowledge

Comment: Thanks archil, if this book is good to start by compariso with previous approach, then we will definetly purchase it.

Comment: Yes it is. Actually, the comparison chapter (first one) is even in amazon's look inside

Answer (score 1):

i hope this one may be of help too.
http://kbochevski.blogspot.com/2011/06/architecting-loosely-coupled-mvcnet.html

Answer (score 0):

You can follow some video tutorials on [pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/tableofcontents?courseName=aspdotnet-mvc3). It's not that expensive and one month is quite enough.

There are also plenty of books that may help you during your learning process. 
I would suggest this one
[Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework 3rd Edition](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-3rd/dp/1430234040/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1311610855&sr=8-2)

[image: Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework 3rd Edition]

The official [site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials) for asp.net mvc has also some great tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with what in my opinion is the best tutorial on ASP.NET MVC 3 and the Entity Framework 4.1.   Go to

[MVC Music Store](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/)

I have tried several tutorials and that one is the best.  It comes with a PDF that leads you through the process.  Next comes the razor view engine syntax, something you definitely need to learn.  Here is a good book on Programming Razor

[Programming Razor](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781449312824)

You must learn the Razor syntax and the razor view engine to build ASP.NET MVC 3 websites.

Comment: Razor is not a MUST use for MVC3, you can use the (icky, horrible) webforms if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have had an introduction, lets get down to it.   First, a word of caution about one particular book on MVC 3

[Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/microsoft-aspdotnet/9781430234043)

This book has an excellent introduction to the MVC architecture and MVC design pattern, related design patterns and programming techniques.  However, its tutorial is riddled with bugs and omissions. Basically, the CRUD code doesnt work.  After you have ground through several chapters of code, you find that when you call SaveChanges(), nothing happens, not even an error.  I downloaded the sample code and ran it and not even it works.  Take that book with a grain of salt.  It appears to have been released without proper editing and validation of the code. I am going to try to get my tokens back for downloading that book on safari.oreilly.com. The MvcMusicStore tutorial is a much better one and the code actually works.

Now we come to a book that pretty much nails programming ASP.NET MVC 3, Razor and the Entity Framework

[Professional ASP.NET MVC 3](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781118155370)

This book is based on the very good MVC Music Store tutorial and expands on it quite nicely.  It will get you started much faster and has much better practical information for getting a well designed, complete MVC application up and running quickly.  The Entity Framework code-first tutorial is excellent.  It is also a short 450 or so pages but there is a lot packed in that book.

You may also want to spend some time learning the Entity Framework 4.1 and LINQ to Entities.  The best book for that is Julie Lehrmans excellent book on LINQ and the Entity Framework

Programming Entity Framework, Second Edition

I am a n00b here so I cant post a link to that book.  You can find it on safari.oreilly.com or go to programmingentityframework.com, Julie's website.   I haven't had a chance to even look at ASP.NET MVC 4!